# How can I cut and insert paste multiple rows in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to cut and insert multiple rows in excel. Below is the error message that I am getting.

> The command you chose cannot be performed with multiple selections. Select a single range and click the command again.

I don’t want to cut and insert paste rows one by one, I would prefer to do this by doing this with multiple rows at once. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In the test data in excel,

```
1.I copied all the cells populated in the rows but not the entire rows. 
2.Then I right clicked and hit cut, then at the left I right clicked 
3. hit insert cut cells.
```

It seems like in excel you can only cut and insert paste one row at once.

Answer (score 1):

This error would not occur (as far as I know) when you are actually selecting whole rows to cut/paste. Are you sure you are making use of the `Ctrl` and `Shift` keys when select these rows.

However it would occur if you try to cut/paste:

**1)** Portions of multiple rows that don't fall within the same column range.

**2)** Portions of multiple columns that don't fall within the same row range.

**3)** A combination of rows and columns

---

***Working examples:***

[image]

---

***Failing examples:***

[image]

---

More information on this error and how to prevent it, right [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/command-cannot-be-used-on-selections)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the non-adjacent rows by holding down the CTRL key
2. Copy the selected rows.
3. Open another sheet (let's say sheet2) and paste the rows.
4. Delete the selected rows in your main sheet.
5. Copy the rows from sheet2 and paste them in your main sheet.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like in excel you can only cut and insert paste one row at
> once.

In Excel, you have to make room for the source cells to copy and paste in the destination, otherwise you may overwrite the existing cells. Below are the 3 steps to follow:

1. Insert [multiple rows](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-in-excel) below the destination cell by selecting the same or larger number of rows as the source and right click "insert" to reserve the room.
2. Highlight the source cells and right click "copy" or ctrl-C.
3. Click the the destination cell and right click "paste" where you can choose to keep source formatting or match destination formatting, such as  copied from Word. If there are extra blank cells, delete them.